# Use javascript to read contents of cache manifest

Tags: javascript, file, cache-manifest

For a web application which can run offline, I have a cache manifest file that contains a comment to indicate when it was last updated:

```
# version: 20131220-1006
```

I'd like to be able to read this version comment line so that I display the version number. Is there a way to get this directly through JavaScript?

(A workaround would be to create a server-side script that will read the version number from the cache manifest file stored on the server, and return that information as a separate operation, but that seems like sledgehammer+nut).

Comment: Javascript can't do file i/o. Unless i've misunderstood, and you're storing the data in localstorage.

Comment: I understand that, on certain browsers, [JavaScript can do file i/o](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: The File API works on files on the client system, the cache manifest resides on the server. If you ever want to expose server data to the client, you must create a service for security reasons.

Comment: @ChrisHardie: I understand that the cache manifest file is downloaded to the client and that its contents are available to the browser. Could you help me to understand why it would be a breach of security to make its contents accessible to JavaScript running in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can not read this version number directly from javascript, but you can actually read content of cache manifest file. Load it with ajax request (jQuery version):

```
    $.get("cache.manifest", function(responseText){
        console.log(responseText);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( "Offline?" );
    });
```

You can fetch version from `responseText` string and save it localstorage. In offline mode you can read value from storage assuming it didnt change.